# How to connect php7 with mongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, php-7

I'm trying to connect PHP 7 with mongoDB, I installed the "new" MongoDB driver using pecl by following this [page](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-php-driver/) instructions. I can see MongoDB version 1.1.8 from `phpInfo()` output, but I can't figure out how to initiate a connection from PHP code :p . the following code includes my attempts to connect (tried to connect even using old fashion way)

```
// new fashion way
$connection = new MongoDB\Driver\Client();

// or by using old fashion way
$conn = new MongoClient();

// random try :p
$randConn = new MongoDB\Client();
```

and in both cases, I'm getting not defined class exception.
please let me know what I'm missing and where is my mistake, please provide and example to be easier to follow if possible ;) .

PS: used operating system is ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

---

thanks in advance.

Comment: have you seen both of these pages yet?https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.tutorial.library.php https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library/tree/master/src

Comment: yes, what is left is to establish a connection. there should be a class to construct (passing connection details) but not able to find it

Comment: It looks like the client class should be `MongoDB\Client`

Comment: already tried this, will add it to tries list also in question.

Comment: and you have downloaded the library, with composer?

Comment: roytuts.com/mongodb-php7-xampp-windows/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The page that you are referring to is the low-level PHP driver for MongoDB. The API is the same as the [HHVM driver for MongoDB](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.tutorial.hhvm.php). The documentation for both of them is the same, and can be found at http://docs.php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php

The driver is written to be a bare bone layer to talk to MongoDB, and therefore misses many convenience features. Instead, these convenience methods have been split out into a layer written in PHP, the [MongoDB Library](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.tutorial.library.php). Using this library should be your **preferred** way of interacting with MongoDB.

The library needs to be installed with [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/), a package manager for PHP. See also [Get Composer: Installation on Linux/OSX](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-linux-unix-osx)

For example:

```
composer require "mongodb/mongodb=^1.0.0"
```

Once you have it installed, you can try connecting using:

```php
<?php
 require 'vendor/autoload.php';
 $collection = (new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017"))->dbname->coll;
?>
```

See also:

- [Doc: MongoDB PHP Library](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-php-library/)
- [MongoDB PHP Library: Getting Started](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-php-library/getting-started/)
- [PHP MongoDB Driver](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/php/)

Comment: Thank you, that's what was missing